# PCRE2: Reading values of pcre2_real_code_n struct

Tags: c++, c, pcre

I'm completely lost in this library because it's very hardcore C code, full of macros and such yummy things.

In my code, I'm generating a JIT compiled regex, the usual way...

```
rc = pcre2_jit_compile(rex.code, PCRE2_JIT_COMPLETE);
```

Nothing special, `rex.code` is a `pcre2_code*` typed variable. From source and from the internet I could dig that under the hood it's possibly a struct of: `pcre2_real_code_8`. After creation I would like to check one of the members of this struct, but compiler says I can't:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'pcre2_real_code_8'
```

How is this possible that I can create a pointer to this struct, but the struct is actually not defined - so, I can't access its elements?

Is there any way to actually accesss the internals in a non-undefined-behaviour way?

Even if it's not meant to be modified, I'd like to only READ one of the members, because I have to keep track of some things that should be out of scope

---

Ps.:
I don't think it should affect the question, but the environment is the following:

- MSVC 2019 with its own compiler
- In my application which I link the PCRE2 to is a C++ app
- Using single byte (8bit) unit size
- I'm using PCRE2 as a static library and just including the "pcre2.h" in the other project.
- [I've built this project](https://github.com/kiyolee/pcre2-win-build) - should be the same as the official one
- As you guessed I'm using Windows

Comment: Much like stdio's `FILE`, It's an opaque structure that you shouldn't be attempting to access fields of. It's not even defined in the public `pcre2.h` header. Wanting to do that smells like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: If you don't need utmost regex performance and you code in C++, have a look at the built-in `std::regex` instead. If you don't code in C++, please kindly remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @rustyx my code is in c++, however the post might not actually C++, I'm unsure if it's needed or not :) I'm glad to use std::regex, if it had good performance, but pcre2 is more than a hundred times faster according to my observations.

Comment: @Shawn You're right, it MIGHT be an xy issue, but because the "issue" I'm facing is kind of hacky, I'm pretty sure it doesn't have a perfect solution. I need to track the RWX pages allocated by my program in memory. PCRE2 allocates one at JIT compilation. I'm pretty sure it must be in that struct.